# Android ViewModel object recreate with kotlin but not with java

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata

Im new to kotlin, and mvvm, but i was able to make it work in java, but when i made a new example mvvm-retrofit-corutines in kotlin, the view model gets called all the time on the OnCreate function is called, (which shouldn't happen according to docs and works fine in java).

MainActivity:

```
lateinit var viewModel : MyViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    //Here we can see the logs in every orientation changed in the emulator.
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
    viewModel.getMutableLiveDataModel().observe(this, Observer {
        Log.d("zzzz","lamda executes onChanged method -> "+ it.otherValues). //element from model
    })
}
```

MyViewModel:

```
 class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

private lateinit var objectTypeModel: MutableLiveData<MyTestModel>

fun getMutableLiveDataModel():MutableLiveData<MyTestModel>{

    //Gets the model from a retrofit service call
    objectTypeModel = MyRepository.getModelFromService()

    return objectTypeModel
}
}
```

Am i doing something wrong?  already tried convert 'viewModel' into local variable as suggested in other post.

> Java Code, MainActivity

```
MyViewModel model;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    model =  new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
    model.getUsers().observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Integer users) {
            Log.d("zzzz","updated value..")
        }
    });
}
```

> Model

```
 public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {

private MutableLiveData<Integer> users;
public LiveData<Integer> getUsers() {
    if (users == null) {
        users = new MutableLiveData<Integer>();
        users.setValue(10);
    }
    return users;
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it gets call every time? It's the same thing happening in Java as well *(Kotlin is just a wrapper, it depends on JVM internally for Android)*. On every configuration change `onCreate` gets called and whatever written inside of it also gets executed. But with the help of ViewModel you can retain data across configuration changes so that you don't loose it.

Comment: That's exactly where im lost.. the equivalent code in java works fine.. i rotate the device, and there's no other log showing, unless i modify the value of my model in my viewmodel

Comment: Can you please share your java code as well just to verify what's happening there?

Comment: Could you add more info on what exactly is wrong here? Both of you VMs are doing different things so it's no surprise you're getting different results as it stands.

Comment: Its simple, the kotlin code is not saving the state when rotating, the java does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried the same concept and as expected, the functionality in **Java** and **Kotlin** is identical. In the LogCat, I expected that the log should be printed on every rotation and it does. Now, let me tell you why it happens.

So, as per the documentation `ViewModel` instance stays alive after the configuration change. Basically, `ViewModel` uses the same instance if your activity is re-creating numerous times but it's not getting destroyed (calling `finish()`). But it's not the magic of the `ViewModel` it's the magic of `LiveData`.

`LiveData` is an observable data view holder so it sends the latest preserved value to the active observers on every configuration change which you're observing in the `onCreate()`.

Let me present you my code.

**Java**

```
// Activity

public class JavaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "JavaActivity";

    private JavaViewModel javaViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_java);

        // Ignore this listener
        findViewById(R.id.go_to_kotlin_activity).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        // Main
        javaViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(JavaViewModel.class);
        javaViewModel.getJavaLiveData().observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Integer integer) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: " + integer);
            }
        });
    }
}

// ViewModel

public class JavaViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<Integer> javaLiveData;

    public LiveData<Integer> getJavaLiveData() {
        if(javaLiveData == null) {
            javaLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
            javaLiveData.setValue(10);
        }
        return javaLiveData;
    }
}
```

**Kotlin**

```
// Activity

class KotlinActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "KotlinActivity"
    }

    private lateinit var kotlinViewModel: KotlinViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_kotlin)

        // Ignore this listener
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.go_to_java_activity_btn).setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this, JavaActivity::class.java))
        }

        // Main
        kotlinViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(KotlinViewModel::class.java)
        kotlinViewModel.getKotlinLiveData().observe(this, Observer {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: $it")
        })
    }
}

// ViewModel

class KotlinViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private lateinit var kotlinLiveData: MutableLiveData<Int>

    fun getKotlinLiveData(): LiveData<Int> {
        if (!::kotlinLiveData.isInitialized) {
            kotlinLiveData = MutableLiveData()
            kotlinLiveData.value = 10
        }
        return kotlinLiveData
    }
}
```

If you have any follow-up questions, leave them in comments.
Thanks!

**References**

- [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) - Official Documentation
- [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) - Official Documentation
- This is a great [article](https://blog.mindorks.com/android-viewmodels-under-the-hood) on how `ViewModel` works internally.
- Do read this [article](https://blog.mindorks.com/understanding-livedata-in-android) as well

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to recreate view model declare your view model like this

```
 private val model: MyViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

for more details refer  [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

Comment: The code in the question is **already** in an activity. There is no `activityViewModels()` for an activity.

Comment: i gave it a try, exactly as it is in the docs:  'val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()'
but the result was the same.. still showing logs on orientation changed.

Comment: what if you assign the model in that statement? `private val model: MyViewModel by activityViewModels() {ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)}`. AFAIK the code in curly brackets shouldn't execute more than once

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue lies in your kotlin viewmodel class, if you are not getting the value(unless you have few more issues in other classes)

1. Fix your kotlin viewmodel class in which data is not set in MutableLiveData, you forgot to add a piece of code.

   ```
    //Here it is like this
    objectTypeModel.value= MyRepository.getModelFromService()
   ```
2. AFAIK onCreate() only gets called when activity is created. So its natural if your viewmodel is getting created again. You can also check it by `init{}` method in your viewmodel class.
3. Still if you are not satisfied move your api call from activity's `onCreate()` method to viewmodels `init{}` method and just observe the changes from Activity. Your `getMutableLiveDataModel()` will called once when viewmodel object gets created.
4. If your java viewmodel example is running as you expected. Then,try to convert the java class to kotlin and run it again(just paste the java code to a kotlin file, it will ask you to convert it), it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try

> **MainActivity**

```
lateinit var viewModel : MyViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
    viewModel.objectTypeModel.observe(this, Observer {
        Log.d("zzzz","lamda executes onChanged method -> "+ it.otherValues).         
        //element from model
    })
}
```

> **ViewModel**

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val objectTypeModel= MutableLiveData<MyTestModel>()

    init {
        objectTypeModel.value = MyRepository.getModelFromService()

    }
}
```